# Linux process virtual memory column in TOP/HTOP

Tags: linux, process, virtual-memory

I wrote a C++ process which is running inside a VMWare machine with a 512Mb of assigned RAM.

I see by TOP/HTOP that the VIRT column shows a value of 490Mb. Instead other processes show few Kbytes for the same field.

Do you know why? Have I to setup something for my process?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a good explanatio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twQKAoq2OPE)n that I'm going to see and learn...

**Edit (2016-04-07):** I've just seen it, and it is brilliant! Please look at /proc//smaps to know how physical ram is used by your process.

**Edit (2016-04-08):** I'm going deeper into the problem, and I discovered that each time I create a thread the process increases the used VIRT. I have seen also that all other linux processes with threads allocate much of VIRT memory size, **so I think it is absolutely normal**!

Answer (score 0):

Virt really doesn't matter, use -a with the resident size. Virt will show even pages that have been swapped out, and I think it's probably useless for what you're trying to figure out.

Comment: Thank you, but where I have to use -a with? And, I understand that it doesn't matter, but why do top display a value so high only for my C++ process?

Comment: -a sorts by memory usage.

Comment: -a sorts by memory usage. If you're looking at virt instead of res, you're also looking at mapped pages that could (probably) not actually allocated. For example, if I mmap(NULL, ...), I can probably get gigs of memory that will show up in virt, but not in res, because they haven't actually been allocated. That's also one of the reasons for shared libraries.